# coreaudiod constantly at around 12.5% CPU on Catalina

Tags: macos, core-audio, macos-catalina

I've upgraded from Mojave to Catalina, and I noticed the fans on my MacBook Pro (15", 2019) are making a lot of noise. I looked into the Activity Monitor, and noticed that `coreaudiod` is constantly at around 12.5% CPU (dropping to no less than 12.2% at times).

I looked around for similar issues, and it seems that the solution is always to restart the service, which I did but it made no difference: The moment it goes back up, within seconds it's back at 12.5%.

I also tried rebooting, and tried closing certain apps and waiting to see if that might calm `coreaudiod` down, but no luck.

Do I have any other options, or do I just need to hope it's a bug with Catalina that Apple's aware of and that they'll release a fix soon?

I wouldn't mind it so much if the constant whirring of the fans didn't drive me crazy.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Rob's right -- Maybe a little more useful, this would fit perfectly at https://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the Audio preferences folder is missing for your user. I solved this with a variation of the solution linked to by dafal:

1. Create a new user on the Mac
2. Log in as the new user
3. Copy the folder `~/Library/Preferences/Audio` somewhere where your main user can reach it – a USB stick for example. I copied it to the `Public` folder of my main user.
4. Log out and log back in as your main user
5. Copy the Audio folder into `~/Library/Preferences` of your main user.

For me, the fans stopped running within seconds after I did this. I verified that `coreaudiod`was down to 0.0% cpu. No restart was necessary.

(To access the Library folder in the Finder, hold down the shift key while you open the "Go" menu. One of the items in the menu will be "Library").

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm a bit confused though: When I created a new user I couldn't find the directory you mentioned. And actually coreaudiod didn't even appear in the Activity Monitor. Could it be that there's a deeper audio related change in Catalina?

Comment: Hi GabeL! For me, the Audio directory didn't appear until I actually logged in with the new user – I assume it's done while the "first login" wizard is being shown. I haven't read up on the changes in Catalina so I don't really know, but to me it looks like the Audio preferences get lost during the upgrade to Catalina. It may be a bit of sloppy programming that causes coreaudiod to go into some internal loop if the directory is not present.

I see the same as you: coreaudiod is not running when I login as the new user. When I login as my main user, it's back, but using 0.0% CPU.

Comment: Hi Rolf! I managed to find the directory and looks like it sorted this issue out! It's worth noting that I did login to the new user but the directory didn't exist (or at least wasn't visible) until I made that user an administrator and rebooted. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Simpler: `mkdir ~/Library/Preferences/Audio; sudo chown _coreaudiod:admin ~/Library/Preferences/Audio`. In my case, I then killed coreaudiod (letting it restart the next time I used sound), although perhaps that was unneeded? The process still uses ~10% CPU  while playing sounds, and for a few seconds afterwards, but then finally drops to nothing.

Comment: I did what @WilliamMcBrine  suggested, and it worked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 9):

I haven't found any effect from creating the `~/Library/Preferences/Audio` directory, but as others have mentioned, sometimes the problem can be caused by a particular app that uses audio. To this end, running `lsof | grep -i coreaudio` in a terminal can help find what this app might be. Quit the apps it returns one by one until the CPU usage stops.

The problem app in my case was, surprisingly, NightOwl, a menubar widget for automatically switching dark/light modes. It plays an owl sound when it switches, but apparently it doesn't release some audio resource afterwards. I hope Apple can find a way to make the system audio interface less prone to this sort of thing.

Comment: Best answer IMO because it provides a way to figure out what the problem is on my machine, whereas the others are just instances of a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

Posting one more answer just in case someone has the same issue as I had.

So I had the same issue - coreaudiod was using 10-12% of cpu all the time.
I've tried the accepted answer, and it didn't help.

The reason in my case was that I was using Citrix to access my remote PC.
There is a bug in Citrix - https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/397283-receiver-1291-high-cpu-10-coreaudiod/.

```
Any sound delivered by Citrix Viewer from the target system, causes coreaudiod to consume ~10% CPU.
```

So the solution for me was to completely mute any sounds on my remote machine.
That did help in my case.

Comment: I had the same issue coreaudiod was using 10-12% of cpu all the time.           The above comment pointed me in the right direction. For me it was due to Microsoft Remote Desktop configured to play sounds locally, even when no sounds are to be played cpu is consumed by core audio.

Comment: Thanks Gary Liddle. I ran lsof | grep -i coreaudio , and it indicated a Microsoft app consumed a lot of resources. That turned out to be Microsoft Remote Desktop also.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me was VMWare. I didn't even have a VM running, but if VMWare is open, coreaudiod seems to spike from 1-3% to 10-15%